# Links to games created by Windows when exes with specific names are executed

Tags: windows-7

I have a Delphi project called VR that produces an executable named VR.exe. To my dismay I discovered Windows (I am running Window 7 64 bit Ultimate) has added links to the start menu and under games: Search & Rescue: Vietname MED+EVAC. The icons for the links are the default delphi app icon.

Did a bit of research and I found this post:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a5919fc1-db3d-4f13-b241-d059df2bf11f/renaming-a-file-into-vrexe

How can I prevent windows from doing this?

Update: I have another project MM, which produces mm.exe. This one created a link to the Steam Dark Messiah Might and Magic Single Player.

Comment: I think you can just disable games explorer.

Comment: I want to keep games explorer :-) I play from time to time, rarely though.